# Slicing outside numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2d matrix, for instance:

```
A = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
          [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

how can I select `NxN` window around a given element so that the window is filled with an arbitrary (e.g. mean) value if it goes outside the original array?

Example:

```
neighbors(A, x=0, y=0, N=3)
```

would yield

```
array([[ 2.5,  2.5,  2.5],
       [ 2.5,    0,    1],
       [ 2.5,    4,    5]])
```

Comment: On a side note, if you're wanting to operate "moving window" style on an nD array and pad the boundaries similar to this, have a look at `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) your array. Padding will extend your array with the desired boundary conditions (see the `mode` parameter for all possible options):

```
>>> A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
                  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
                  [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
                  [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> N = 5 # 5x5 windows
>>> B = np.pad(A, N//2, mode='reflect')
>>> B
array([[10,  9,  8,  9, 10, 11, 10,  9],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  5],
       [ 2,  1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  1],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  5],
       [10,  9,  8,  9, 10, 11, 10,  9],
       [14, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13],
       [10,  9,  8,  9, 10, 11, 10,  9],
       [ 6,  5,  4,  5,  6,  7,  6,  5]])
```

As you can see, the original array is in the center of the matrix, padded by 2 rows and 2 columns (`N//2 = 5//2 = 2`, both from lef/right and bottom/top). The padded elements are *reflected*.

For this new array, you can access to the desired neighbours window by just normally indexing the array:

```
>>> x = 1; y = 1 # corresponds to number 5 in the original array
>>> B[y:y+N, x:x+N]
array([[ 5,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 9,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [13, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

You can choose other padding methods, *mean* is one of the options.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not too far off:

```
def neighbors(arr, x, y, N):
    left = max(0, x - N)
    right = min(arr.shape[0], x + N)
    top = max(0, y - N)
    bottom = min(arr.shape[1], y + N)

    window = arr[left:right+1,top:bottom+1]
    fillval = window.mean()

    result = np.empty((2*N+1, 2*N+1))
    result[:] = fillval

    ll = N - x
    tt = N - y
    result[ll+left:ll+right+1,tt+top:tt+bottom+1] = window

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with [`np.lib.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) and [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
Ap = np.lib.pad(A.astype(float),1, 'constant', constant_values=(np.nan,np.nan))
Acut = Ap[np.ix_(np.arange(N)+x,np.arange(N)+y)]
Acut[np.isnan(Acut)] = np.nanmean(Acut)
```

Sample run -

```
In [76]: A
Out[76]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [77]: x=1; y=0; N = 3

In [78]: Ap = np.lib.pad(A.astype(float),1, 'constant', constant_values=(np.nan,np.nan))
    ...: Acut = Ap[np.ix_(np.arange(N)+x,np.arange(N)+y)]
    ...: Acut[np.isnan(Acut)] = np.nanmean(Acut)
    ...: 

In [79]: Acut
Out[79]: 
array([[ 4.5,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 4.5,  4. ,  5. ],
       [ 4.5,  8. ,  9. ]])
```